# Tus server Integration with shrine "Dealing with large uploads filesize > 1 gb"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, shrine, tus

I am trying to integrate the [tus-server](https://github.com/janko-m/tus-ruby-server) with [shrine](https://shrinerb.com/) to upload the video files to Vimeo.

`Client.js`

```
this.uppy = new Uppy({
  id: 'uppy1',
  autoProceed: false,
  debug: true,
  restrictions: {
    allowedFileTypes: ['.mp4'],
  },
  allowMultipleUploads: true,
})
  .use(Tus, { endpoint: `${API_BASE}/files` })
 /* .use(XHRUpload, { endpoint: `${API_BASE}/files`,
    formData: true,
    bundle: false,
    fieldName: 'file',
    headers: getHeaders(), */
 })
  .use(GoogleDrive, { serverUrl: 'https://companion.uppy.io' })
  .use(Dropbox, { serverUrl: 'https://companion.uppy.io/' });
```

---

```
# config/routes.rb (Rails)
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Tus::Server => "/files"
end
```

Here, by default, the server directly uploads the file to the `data/` folder with a file in the project root.

What I want to achieve is to upload the `video` files to Vimeo.

Like:

1. File goes to `${API_BASE}/files`
2. Mine controller gets the file
3. I pass the file to Vimeo (using [vimeo_me2](https://github.com/bo-oz/vimeo_me2))
4. Vimeo uploads the file and sends the video_url back. I now insert the video_url in a certain video table.
5. All these above processes need to be resumable.

I am using [vimeo_me2](https://github.com/bo-oz/vimeo_me2) gem.

Can Anyone provide a solution to integrate/configure Tus server with Shrine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of tus-ruby-server and Shrine here :)

You have two options as far as I'm concerned: use Vimeo's "pull upload", or upload directly to Vimeo.

## A. Pull upload

Vimeo's [pull upload](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#pull-upload) allows you to give Vimeo the link to your file, and let it download and save the file for you. This should be resumable, because tus-ruby-server supports [range requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests), and it seems that Vimeo will use that:

> We even handle any connectivity issues that might come up.

The `vimeo_me2` gem has a [method](https://github.com/bo-oz/vimeo_me2/tree/6d09c58acf06c7a333178a51142cb42114b59c4e#utilizing-the-vimeo-pull-request) for pull upload. So you can just give it the link to the tus file, e.g if you have a `Movie` with a `video` attachment:

```
vimeo_client.pull_upload("Name of video", movie.video.url)
```

## B. Direct upload to Vimeo

Vimeo also [implements](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#resumable-guide) the tus resumable upload protocol, so theoretically it should be possible to use Uppy to upload directly to Vimeo. In that case you could get rid of `tus-ruby-server`.

I haven't personally tried this approach. It seems like there is an extra first step of creating the video, but the rest of it looks like the standard tus protocol. These is an [example app](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy-vimeo-thing/blob/master/app.js) created by the authors of Uppy, so I think you should be able to copy-paste a lot of the stuff from there.

---

The approach I **don't** recommend is downloading the file from the tus server and uploading it to Vimeo using the `vimeo_me2` gem. Firstly, the download won't be resumable, as the [`down`](https://github.com/janko-m/down) gem that [`shrine-tus`](https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine-tus) uses doesn't yet support resumable downloads. Secondly, while `vimeo_me2` [uses the tus protocol](https://github.com/bo-oz/vimeo_me2/blob/master/lib/vimeo_me2/user/upload.rb#L51-L62) for uploading, it doesn't seem to do anything to resume the upload in case of connection errors. It also appears to load the whole file into memory.

In any case, options A and B will be more performant.

Comment: ATM I won't be dealing with approach A. 

Approach B might be what I am looking for.
If I implement direct upload to Vimeo from clientside, I need to look after success or error response sent from the Vimeo and send an API request to the mine server and update the video table with Vimeo `data_url` if the response is a success.

Comment: ATM I'm not dealing with Oauth. I'll just use the public `access_token` from vimeo and every user can upload videos in mine account. (No oauth req.).

I looked at [vimeo-uppy-thing](https://github.com/transloadit/uppy-vimeo-thing/blob/master/app.js). It involves whole oauth procedure and I even didn't get much of it. What mine concern is user selects the video from uppy dashboard clicks the Upload button video gets uploaded to Vimeo. That's it (no oauth).

Comment: To my knowledge these are the only two solutions with acceptable performance, and both are implementable.

Comment: So, if I need to upload videos to AWS s3 bucket. What approaches should I take?
Using uppy `aws s3 multipart` plugin.

Comment: Docs say that i need to create an companion server for that?

Comment: You can use either `aws s3 multipart` or `tus` Uppy plugin, whichever one you prefer. For `aws s3 multipart` approach you can either use Uppy's Companion (Node app) or the [uppy-s3_multipart](https://github.com/janko-m/uppy-s3_multipart) Ruby gem, while for `tus` approach you can use the official [tusd](https://github.com/tus/tusd) server (Go app), or [tus-ruby-server](https://github.com/janko-m/tus-ruby-server) that's written in Ruby.